# Sending an email to office365 via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, email, office365

I am attempting a script that will send me the output in an email. I got most of it working but when sending an email it want me to put in my password. is there a way to add this into the script?  I have the user id down but not the password. I am sure it is something simple. basically  I want computer b to run this script. and email me back info to computer a both are on two different networks. If I don't know the IP of computer b. Here is what I have so far:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “mypassword” -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 
(“support@email.com.com”, $secpasswd)

Send-MailMessage -To "support@email.com" -SmtpServer "smtp.office365.com" -
Credential $mycreds -UseSsl "Backup Notification" -Port "587" -Body "This a 
Test Message.<br>Brought to you by PowerShell.<br> Hopefully this will help 
setup VPN Connections<b>Thanks</b>" -From "support@email.com" -BodyAsHtml
```

I am testing this by sending myself an email, I always seem to get the following error:

```
 Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server 
response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM 
[DM5PR20CA0014.namprd20.prod.outlook.com]
At C:\Users\502706436\Desktop\tight vnc\test email 1.ps1:6 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -To "support@email.com" -SmtpServer "smtp.office365 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], Smtp 
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Had anyone else had an issue like this? I really want to see if this can be done, I know it can but I am missing something...probably something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indicates that the SMTP server configured in your Outgoing Mail Account is connecting to an SMTP client submission endpoint which cannot be used for direct send. So, configure your Exchange SMTP to direct send.

Refer the following:

- [Fix issues with direct send](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fix-issues-with-printers-scanners-and-LOB-applications-that-send-email-using-Office-365-c75542a8-c792-42c0-a8c5-291df987512d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
- [SMTP Client Submission](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-Office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#DirectSendConfig)

Answer (score 0):

I had a face slap moment. the email in my credentials had 2 .com in it. after deleting one of them it works. Thanks anyways.

Comment: That is crazy by the way. Nevertheless, good to know that you got the solution on the same.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for a little different approach to sending an email through Outlook Office365:

```
# Sending an email from PowerShell 5.1 script through outlook.office365.com
#
# 1. Create an encrypted password file
#   PS > Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File -FilePath <passwordfile>
#   This will prompt you for a password, encrypt and save in <passwordfile>
# 2. Obtain Outlook Office365 SMTP server name.
#   Go to your ISP and find the value of the MX record. For example <yourdomain>.mail.protection.outlook.com
# 3. If after running the script you get this error:
#   Send-MailMessage : Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.606 Access denied, banned sending IP [X.X.X.X].
#   You will need to delist your IP by going here: https://sender.office.com/
#   Note:  Removing you IP from the block list could take up to 30 minutes.
#
$User = "<SMPT loging username>"
$PasswordFile = "<passwordfile>"
$SMTPCredentials=New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString)
$EmailTo = "<to email address>"
$EmailFrom = "<from email address>"
$Subject = "<email subject>" 
$Body = "<email body>" 
$SMTPServer = "<Outlook STMP Server from MX record>"
Send-MailMessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port 25 -Credential $SMTPCredentials -UseSsl
```